# Create auto-generate long filed (identifier/unique key) in Solr cluser of Watson retrieve and rank service

Tags: solr, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I want to have auto-generate Long unique key in Solr cluster.
I'm using IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank service and I tried the standard ways of Solr to have auto-generate mechanism (generate UUID, etc), but it's not working for Retrieve and Rank clusters. Maybe IBM is using old version of Solr or it's customized by IBM.

Who had a such a situation and how he/she fixed it?

Then you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in your solrconfig.xml configuration file:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
  <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">id</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I'm using IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank too and it worked for me. I created my collection after adding this configuration. If you already have a collection, check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API) to update an existing configuration.